# jquery mobile and asp.net mvc post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I've got a basic MVC4 page using jQuery mobile, all I'm trying to do is a POST method, normally in ASP.Net MVC it would simply look at my controller for my post, so for example on my MVC page I have a simple submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Save"  data-theme="b" />
```

in which I would expect it to call the controller post method

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MobileEdit(MobileClient client)
        {..}
```

but it does not call this actionresult, I think this is due to jQuery intercepting the the post method and wants to do an AJAX call?

So my question is what do I need to change/add for it to call my controller post method?

Comment: What's your form tag look like?

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm()){..}

Comment: You're view is named `MobileEdit` right?

Comment: yeap im using the same name

Comment: Watch your network tab in your browser console, where is it trying to post? Does it actually post?

Comment: if it helps, if i do a hard refresh on the page, then press the save button the post method is called

Answer (score 0):

Try adding FormMethod.Post to your form

```
using (Html.BeginForm("method","controller",FormMethod.Post))
```

Another thing you could try is to put `data-ajax="false"` or `rel="external"` on the `<a>` tag that bring you to this page with the save button